# Ask for channel ID through a command in Discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I'm new to Discord py and trying to make my bot get the channel ID using a command like >sending [numbers] but it's not actually working. The error I get is

> TypeError: get_channel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

This is how I'm trying to make it:

```
from discord import Client
from discord import channel
from discord.ext import commands

id_chnl = ''

@bot.command()
async def sending(ctx, *, chnl):
    global id_chnl
    id_chnl = cnhl
    global channel
    channel = Client.get_channel(str(id_chnl))
    await ctx.send("Saving your ID")
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your trying to but getting channel object is easy using command by [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#converters).

All you have to do is,

```py
@bot.command()
async def sending(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
     channel_id = channel.id
```

Note: There are different types of channels - `text`, `voice`, `stage`, `category` and `store`. Each of the uses different converters and you can find them in the docs.

If you want to get any one of the channel regardless of the type,

````py
channel: typing.Union[discord.TextChannel, discord.VoiceChannel, discord.StoreChannel, discord.StageChannel, discord.CategoryChannel]```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I was trying to do was to get the ID from a different channel on the same server, so I could filter some of the messages sent by the bot by simply making it send it to the ID I gave it in the command. That's why I complicated myself.

Answer (score 0):

been a bit, but try:

```
channel = Client.get_channel(id=str(id_chnl))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sadly, now this error shows up TypeError: get_channel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @Daniel Rosas I asume you are using Cogs right? Otherwise the `self` argument would be incorrect. So try using `self.client.get_channel(id=str(id_chnl))`

Comment: Thats bc you imported Client and you alr used bot so you cant use Client use bot

Comment: And this function is an async function

Answer (score 0):

The easist way to get the channel the bot is in is:

```
@bot.command()
async def sending(ctx):
     channel_id = ctx.channel.id
```

The easist way to get the channel by using #:

```
@bot.command()
async def sending(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
     channel_id = channel.id
```

To fetch the channel:

```
@bot.command()
async def sending(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
     channel_id = await bot.fetch_channel(channel.id)
```

Alternative way might be using name:

```
@bot.command()
async def sending(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
     channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=channel) #or instead of name it would be id
```

Comment: I think I will try to work with the last one, since what I'm trying to do is give the bot the ID for a different channel in the same server.